# Google charts API - multiple charts on the same image

Tags: google-visualization

Is there a way to display multiple charts on the same image using Google Charts api?

To elaborate:
I have one data series which I want to display as bar chart.
I have another data set which has nothing to do with the first one (well they are correlated but the values are hundred times bigger). 
X-axis is for dates.
I want to have second data set displayed as line chart with Y-axis on the left.

I found something similar in "Compound charts" section but as far as I understand markers are calculated based on already displayed data set - and I want to have them independent.

In other words - is it possible to make image like this:
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvg&chm=D,0033FF,1,0,5,1&chs=200x150&chd=t1:30,10,20|60,40,50&chxt=y

but with the line being independent and their values axis being on the right.

I'm sorry I'm not familiar with the terminology - I'm sure there is a name for what I'm trying to achieve.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Only 2 years behind the curve but just to let you know that I have achieved your objective of displaying 2 datasets (one a bar chart, the other a line chart) against 2 different axis scales.

The devil is in the scaling parameter `&chds` and explicit axis values using `&chxr`. Essentially, I defined the explicit scales for the x-axis, y-axis and r-axis. and then instructed the scaling parameter to scale each dataset differently.

So for an *r* dataset between 0 - 10 and a *y* dataset between 0-2 I would write;

`&chds=0,2,0,10` (y then r defined in my axis parameter, i.e. `&chxt=y,r`)
...and...
`&chxr=0,0,2|1,0,10`

Let me know if you need more detail!

Answer (score 0):

I've looked into something similar to this before and have used the google chart API a lot. I'm 90% sure the answer is no. Sry :(

Answer (score -1):

Yep it is possible.

Here is an example of two datasets displayed on the same axes.  1 is a bar chart the other is a line graph....

This line - chd=t1:95,1,1,3,10,3,77|95,52,44,24,11,2,1 - allows for the two datasets.

slothistype